# Insert data at the top of grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to insert records to a database from asp.net grid view. Inserted records are displaying as a last record in the grid view. But I want to display the record at the top row of the grid view i.e., very next row of header.

Can anyone help me? I have googled a lot but couldn't find best solution.

Comment: Determine which order by gets it in the top of your collection maybe createddate or something else you would know better

Comment: move your whole table one row down and insert new row at place 0(just an idea)

Comment: Just making sure... your GridView is bound using DataBind()?

Comment: I don't get it, don't you just want to sort the records from database with ascending order by their id?

Answer (score 1):

While binding your grid after insertion, sort your result table first for some column value that can put your newly inserted row to the top, may be the id column if it is auto-increment field or some date column etc.
Then bind your grid with your result table.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the  Idea. But I dont want to sort any records.For example we have two grids(grid1,grid2) on a page. select a record from grid1 and click a button to move. The selected record to be added to grid2 on the grid1.rows[0]. Just like a two list boxes.

Comment: Ok, so this is actually your requirement?

Comment: So your one grid is on one page and another one is on another page, but how can you view both the grids together as they are in the different pages? I mean... I think I can provide the solution but I am not at all clear with your requirement

Comment: Actually my requirement is: I have a grid in my webpage with a list of companies.. I want to add some companies from database. For this I have a button which opens a pop up window. displays all the companies in the database with a check box in the grid. select/check some companies in the pop window and click add button in pop window. the selected companies are gets added to this parent window but the companies are added at the end of the grid. But i want to add those records on the top position of the grid.